# Vertical -align middle doesnt work in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I am trying to align the content in the center of the page both vertically and horizontally.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Some random text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a basic HTML layout and added some CSS

```
.parent {
    display:table;
}
.child {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.content {
    text-align:center;
}
```

But it doesn't align in the middle. Am I missing something here?

https://jsfiddle.net/himakar/vc20j1xv/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it something to align to:

Try this:

```
body {
    display:table;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Vertical-align means just that - align, but you have to give the outer a value to align to

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc20j1xv/5/)

I will say though, I wouldn't amend and align to the body like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin: 0 auto` on your `body` element to align it on the center.

```
body {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc20j1xv/6/)

Comment: Apologies, I updated your post by mistake instead of my own

Comment: It seems the OP change the code. But these aligns it to the middle as I try it earlier.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't align vertically